# How can I get indices of elements of nd.array not in a tulple

Tags: numpy

How can I get indices of elements of nd.array not in a tulple, but in nd.array with .ndim==1
E.g. I have array `[1,4,2,1]` and a condition that elements should be less than 3. I tried this code`np.where(array<3)` but it returned me a tuple. Then a tried to convert it into nd.array with `np.array(np.where(array<3))` but after that the ndim was 2.
The output of the example `[1,4,2,1]` Should be `[0,2,3]` and `type(output)==nd.array`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre].

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html says it returns an array, not a tuple.

Comment: @mkrieger1 From the documentation you linked: "When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses. The rest of this documentation covers only the case where all three arguments are provided."

Comment: @user3483203 I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```py
np.where(array<3)[0]
```

`[0]` here takes the firts element of the tuple and this element is of type `np.ndarray`